# I can't change my page background (foundation 5)

Tags: html, css, background, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 5 platform to build my website.

In one of the pages in my website, there is a blank white background - the default one. I tried to change it into an image background, but failed to.

I am adding the code I tried to add to one of my pages' header. Does anyone know why the background stays white? Thank your!!

```
<style>
    html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: maybe the url you put there is wrong?

Comment: this is the url i actually put: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") . I think the default background which comes with Foundation goes above the one I tried to add.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from the amount of information you provided. I'm guessing it is either that the browser cannot find `images/bg.jpg` relative to the path of this HTML file or there is a conflict between CSS declarations. You could try applying this CSS to the `body` element instead of the `html` element. It could also be that another CSS selector has higher precedence and therefore applies instead of this one.

One way to find out is to use your browser's inspector tool. For example, in Chrome, right-click and select "Inspect Element", in the Elements tab, click on the `<html>` element and then check out the styles that are active for it (right-hand Styles pane).

Comment: I've already tried to do that, however I couldn't find any conflict.

Comment: So the Inspector shows that your rules are applied to the root `html` element and they are active?

Comment: yes. I think the way foundation 5 works is that the whole page is covered by one big DIV, but when I try to edit its background, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is this page live somewhere? Can you link to it?

Comment: No, it is local. Are you familiar with Foundation 5? I think once you choose to work with Foundation, things like backgrounds work differently.

Comment: Sorry... Now it works!
The problem was that the url I used was blocked from my domain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the body background has been set to white by default in foundation.

Uncomment and edit line 38 of _settings.scss file from

```
 // $body-bg: #fff;
```

to

```
 $body-bg: transparent;
```